# Error in ajax function while displaying data in form

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying to get the data from database and want to show that data in my form but its gives me the following error VM1704:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input. i have select the data from database in my php file and want to show that data in my form
    at JSON.parse ()
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange (main.php:61)

```
 <form >
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="fathername" id="fathername" class="form-control">
            </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myfunction(id)
        {
            //alert(id);
            console.log(id);
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = myObj.email;
                     document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = myObj.name;
                      document.getElementById("fathername").innerHTML = myObj.fathername;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?q=" + id, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }




    </script>
```

ajax.php file

```
<?php 
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "login";
$records=array();

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM detail WHERE email= '$q' "  ;
$result = $conn->query($sql2);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {


    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $records=array(
            'email'=>$row['email'],
            'name'=>$row['name'],
            'fathername'=>$row['fathername']


        );


    }
}
else
{

}

return  json_encode($records);
?>
```

Comment: Use `echo` instead of `return` in your ajax.php file. `return` doesn't actually output anything.

Comment: it removes the error but stiil data is not displayed in form

Comment: You are also wide open to SQL Injections and should use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Do a `console.log(this.responseText);` in your callback and check if you're actually getting a response. You can also check the network tab in your browsers console to see if the request and the response looks OK.

Comment: Ah. The correct way to set an input-fields value is using `value` instead of `innerHTML`. Example: `document.getElementById("email").value = myObj.email`. Input fields don't have any inner HTML (like divs/spans etc does).

Comment: yeah thank u so much it start working

Comment: I'll write it up as an answer that you can accept, letting people know it's been resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of issues with your code.

#### First issue

You're using `return` instead of `echo`:

```
return json_encode($records);
```

Return doesn't actually output anything. Use `echo` instead:

```
echo json_encode($records);
```

#### Second issue

You're trying to populate the input fields in the wrong way. You're using `.innerHTML` which isn't valid for input fields (they don't have any inner HTML). It's the `value` attribute you want to set:

```
document.getElementById("email").value = myObj.email
```

The same goes for the rest of the input fields.